# On primitive groups with transitive subgroups of smaller degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G$ be primitive on $\Omega$ and $G_\Delta$ transitive on $\Omega-\Delta=\Gamma$.  Let $1 < |\Gamma| \le \frac{1}{2}|\Omega|$. Then $G$ is triply transitive on $\Omega$.  In addition, if $|\Gamma| < \frac{1}{2} |\Omega|$, then $G$ is alternating or symmetric.

The above assertion is from [Wielandt, Theorem 13.5].  I have a question in one step of the proof given in the text.  The proof first introduces sets $\psi,\Delta^*,\Gamma^*$, and in part (a) of the proof the case  $|\psi|>1$ is settled.  In part (b) of the proof, the case where $|\psi|=1$ is considered.  The text mentions that in this case, by 13.6(a), $G_{\Delta^*}$ is doubly transitive on $\Gamma^*$.  However, assertion 13.6(a) only shows that $G_{\Delta^*}$ is transitive, not doubly transitive, on $\Gamma^*$.  Why is 2-fold transitivity true?

Let me recall here Lemma 13.6(a) (which is proved in the text before Theorem 13.5 and which introduces the sets $\psi,\Delta^*,\Gamma^*$ that are used in the proof of Theorem 13.5):

Lemma 13.6(a):  Suppose $G \le S^\Omega$ is primitive on $\Omega$, $\Omega=\Delta \dot{\cup} \Gamma, |\Delta| \ge 1, |\Gamma| \ge 2$, and $G_\Delta$ is transitive on $\Gamma$.  Then $\exists \Gamma \subset \Gamma^* \subset \Omega, \Delta^*:=\Omega-\Gamma^*, \psi:=\Gamma^*-\Gamma$ such that $G_{\Delta^*}$ is transitive on $\Gamma^*$.

The proof of 13.6(a) is as follows.  Since $G$ is not imprimitive, $\Gamma$ is not a block. So $\exists g \in G$ such that $\Gamma,\Gamma^g$ have partial overlap.  Amongst all $g \in G$ such that $\Gamma,\Gamma^g$ have partial overlap, choose a $g$ such that $\Gamma \cup \Gamma^g =: \Gamma^*$ has as few elements as possible.  Then $\langle G_\Delta, g^{-1} G_\Delta g \rangle$ (which is a subgroup of $G_{\Delta^*}$) is transitive on $\Gamma^*$. So $G_{\Delta^*}$ is also transitive on $\Gamma^*$.

---Edit---

After posting the question, I figured it out:  Let $\psi=\{\beta\}$.  Since $G_{\Delta^*}$ is transitive on $\Gamma^*$, and since $(G_{\Delta^*})_\beta= G_\Delta$ is transitive on $\Gamma=\Gamma^*-\beta$, it follows that $G_{\Delta^*}$ is 2-transitive on $\Gamma^*$.